# django-haystack won't index my data

Tags: solr, indexing, django-haystack

I'm following instructions on [haystack documentation.](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#configuratio)

I'm getting no results for SearchQuerySet().all().

I think the problem is here

```
$ ./manage.py rebuild_index

WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index in connection 'default'.
Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y

Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
All documents removed.
Indexing 0 notes. // <-- here 0 notes!
```

mysite/note/search_indexes.py looks like

```
import datetime
import haystack
from haystack import indexes
from note.models import Note

class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user')
    pub_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')

    def get_model(self):
        return Note

    def index_queryset(self):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

and I have mysite/note/templates/search/indexes/note/Note_text.txt

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.user.get_full_name }}
{{ object.body }}
```

[Debugging haystack document](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/debugging.html) mentions

> Do you have a search_sites.py that runs haystack.autodiscover?
>
> Have you registered your models with the main haystack.site (usually
>   within your search_indexes.py)?

But none of search_sites.py , haystack.autodiscover, haystack.site was mentioned in the first article.
I'm so confused. Are their docs dealing with different haystack versions?

My setups are..

haystack version 2.0.0.beta
django 1.3.1
solr 3.6.0
sqlite 3

Comment: In my (silly) case the rebuild_index didn't get index any products because there weren't any (db connection was improper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be...

`def index_queryset(self, using=None):`

I don't know if this will fix your issue or not, but that is the correct signature for the method.

Answer (score 2):

```
def index_queryset(self):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

was the culprit.

I don't know why, but commenting out fixes the problem.
I guess 'time' in my system is somehow messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Removing **def index_queryset(self)** makes sense. It builds a regular Django ORM **QuerySet**, which decides which objects get put into the full-text index. Your sample **index_queryset** limits the objects to **past timestamps** only (before **now**).

So, you really have a **datetime handling** problem. Check your SQL database's **timezone** and how it stores times.

A timestamp in UTC locale is about +5 hours ahead of New York, and most of the USA. SQLite caused the same problem for me by choosing UTC times in the future.